# jquery onchange get enter key

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
        $("#temperature").change(function (e) {
// elaboration
});
</script>

   @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {   
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <div class="form-group" id="TemperatureGroup">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.temperature, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.temperature, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.temperature, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <div id="infoPaintTemperature" class="col-md-10">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Salva" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I need to catch if the user have press Enter key inside the input "Temperature", to prevent elaboration of "change" javascript. I can't find anywhere how to get the info of which key has been pressed inside "change" function.
Thanks for who can help

**EDIT**

I would like to do two different elaboration in .change() if I leave the textbox or if I press Enter inside textbox.

Comment: `e.keyCode == 13` is what you are looking for.

Comment: For details, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode

Comment: I tried , but e.keyCode inside $("#temperature").change(function (e)  is undefine.

Comment: Hi, jquery doc. https://api.jquery.com/event.which/

Comment: inside ("#temperature").change(function (e) {} e.type return "change". e.which, e.keyCode, e.key return all undefine

Comment: JQuery doc example use on( "keydown

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to trigger some function (elaboration inside "change" event callback) only if the user leaves the input box.

If that is the case then you can try using the `.focusout((event) => {})` method of javascript.

It will be only triggered when input is focused out and inside which you can compare the currentInput value with previousInput value and accordingly trigger run the logic.

```js
$(function () {
    let previousInput = '' // blank for first time use
    $("#temperature").focusout(function(e){
        // console.log(e.target.value)
        if (previousInput !== e.target.value) {
            // Input changed
            previousInput = e.target.value
            // rest of elaboration
        } else {
            // Input not changed
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you for answer, but the goal is to understand if the user press the enter key inside the textbox, instead of leave the textbox, because the enter key will submit the page, so the elaboration have to do a different code in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this;

```
$('input').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == '13') {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).blur()
    };
});
```

Which when the user presses ENTER will enact `blur` which can also enact the `change`.

`.preventDefault();` will stop the form submitting when ENTER is pressed.

Answer (score -1):

you muse use delegate to attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector, now or in the future, based on a specific set of root elements, and you can use .temperature

> $( ".form-horizontal" ).delegate( ".temperature", "change", function()
> { }

Comment: model.temperature only show with loop so you must use delegate to create new event for element

Comment: You clearly didn't read the docs. It was superseded by `on()` years ago and is now deprecated

Comment: The .on() syntax is the new syntax that version 1.7 uses and it is meant to substitute .bind(), .delegate() and .live().

Comment: 1.7 is far from new, it is about 10 years old